# Can I use a Lightning Component in the Winter '16 Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

I created both a Lightning App, and a Lightning Component, and I can't find solid documentation on using either in the Winter '16 Lightning Experience. Can anyone direct me to documentation using either of these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Jenny B's comment, here's a list of where you can use the components (with tutorial links):

- [Standalone apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.lightning.meta/lightning/qs_aotp_app.htm)
- [Salesforce1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_salesforce1.htm)
- [Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_lex.htm)
- [Lightning App Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm)
- [Community Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder.htm)

Basically, you can surface your components in the Salesforce1 navigation menu by implementing the `force:appHostable` interface and creating a custom tab for it. Similarly, you can make them available via the App Launcher in Lightning Experience. Those tutorials show you how. You might also be interested in the [Lightning App Builder Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lightning_app_builder) and the [Communities Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/).

Another useful way of surfacing the components in Lightning Experience via the Lightning App Builder is shown at 52:00 of this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tFhbrORJwo). Update: This might not be GA yet.

Answer (score 5):

They have a module on where Lightning Components can be used in Trailhead [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_dev/lex_dev_overview/lex_dev_overview_lightning_components):

> Okay, so we know what to consider. But where exactly can you use
>   Lightning components? With the Winter ’16 release, you have several
>   options.
>
> Standalone Apps
>
> If you used Lightning components in Salesforce Classic, you probably
>   made at least one standalone Lightning app. Lightning App Builder lets
>   you declaratively create apps with standard components ranging from
>   buttons to Canvas apps. Alternatively, use the Developer Console to
>   create apps made up of both standard and custom Lightning components.
>   See the Lightning Component Developer’s Guide for more information.
>
> Salesforce1
>
> We’re repeating this one often because it’s very important: use
>   Lightning components for your mobile development. When you’re using a
>   mobile device, you don’t want to make a call to the server every time
>   a user presses a button. Using Lightning components vastly improves
>   mobile app performance.
>
> Visualforce Pages
>
> This capability is perfect for Salesforce developers that are
>   Visualforce veterans. If you’re not quite ready to commit to a full
>   Lightning app, smooth the transition by integrating components into
>   Visualforce pages. This task only requires a few lines of markup and
>   gives you a huge amount of flexibility. See the Lightning Component
>   Developer’s Guide for more information.
>
> As much engineering effort as we’ve put into making Lightning
>   components a framework you can use to create applications for the next
>   decade, we’re not done. There’s still a few places where you can use
>   Visualforce to customize Salesforce but you can’t yet use Lightning
>   components. Stay tuned to this channel.

Also from the release notes [here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_applauncher_component.htm):

> Make Your Lightning Components Available For Lightning Experience
>
> Include your components in the App Launcher for Lightning Experience
>   users.
>
> In the components you wish to include in Lightning Experience, add
>   implements="force:appHostable" in the aura:component tag and save your
>   changes.
>
> ```
> <aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
> ```
>
> The appHostable interface makes the component available as a custom
>   tab.
>
> Follow these steps to include your components in Lightning Experience
>   and make them available to users in your organization.
>
> Create a custom tab for this component.
>
> From Setup, enter Tabs in the Quick Find box, then select Tabs.
>
> Click New in the Lightning Component Tabs related list.
>
> Select the Lightning component that you want to make available to
>   users.
>
> Enter a label to display on the tab.
>
> Select the tab style and click Next.
>
> When prompted to add the tab to profiles, accept the default and click
>   Save.
>
> Assign your Lightning components to a custom app.
>
> Create a custom app and name it Lightning.
>
> Select the Lightning app you created and then click Edit.
>
> In the Custom App Edit page, select the components you want to
>   include, click Add, and then Save.
>
> Check your output by navigating to the App Launcher in Lightning
>   Experience. Your custom app should appear in theApp Launcher. Click
>   the custom app to see the components you added.