# Expose a lightning component to salesforce classic

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce-classic

I want to expose a lightning component to salesforce classic.

I know we expose the component using visualforce page (refer this [link](http://www.forcewizard.com/blog/expose-your-lightning-components-visualforce-page)) but is there a way that we can directly expose it to the salesforce classic UI using some features.

Comment: I would think not. Lighting is a completely different approach and architecture as far as i know. Look at this question for where lighting is allowed to be used http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93655/can-i-use-a-lightning-component-in-the-winter-16-lighting-experience

Comment: Now that I wrote my answer...now I'm wondering if you mean salesforce-classic mobile?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done these days using Lightning Out on a visualforce page:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/lightning-components-visualforce-lightning.html

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as so. I also want to add to it and say lightning web components can also be used in classic this way. Just wrap the lwc with an aura component and follow the above steps.

Answer (score 1):

I have not attempted it, because to me it feels like using technology for technology sake, but I have mused about creating a Lightning .app page and accessing it from the classic UI. I could see potentially doing this in an iFrame via a custom web tab, or from a custom URL link button.

However I suspect the experience of such a cobbled approach would make for a crappy user experience without some kind of extreme UI acrobatics. So my own contempt-prior-to-investigation (and limited amount of time to experiment) has prevented me from attempting this to see how it might work.

But hey...feel free to give it a try. If it works and your users like it, write a blog post and tweet about it.

But for me, if I plan to build a custom UI for the classic UI, Visualforce gives me all kinds of tools to do this already. That's how I would do it.

**Update:** I just tested the web tab option, and it fails due to serving of lightning urls resources with the header: `X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN`. So give the custom button a try, maybe?